# Load CSV files in dictionary then make data frame for each csv file Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have multiple csv files
I was able to load them as data frames into dictionary by using keywords

```
# reading files into dataframes
csvDict = {}
for index, rows in keywords.iterrows():
    eachKey = rows.Keyword
    csvFile = "SRT21" + eachKey + ".csv"
    csvDict[eachKey] = pd.read_csv(csvFile)
```

Now I have other functions to apply on every data frame's specific column.

on a single data frame the code would be like this

```
df['Cat_Frames'] = df['Cat_Frames'].apply(process)

df['Cat_Frames'] = df['Cat_Frames'].apply(cleandata)

df['Cat_Frames'] = df['Cat_Frames'].fillna(' ')
```

My question is how to loop through every data frame in the dictionary to apply those function?

I have tried

```
for item in csvDict.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(item)
    df
```

and it gives me empty result

any solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Items returns a tuple of key/value, so you should make your for loop actually say:

```
for key, value in csvDict.items():
  print(df)
```

also you need to print the df if you aren't in jupyter

Comment: What is `df` above? I see `key` and `value` (a data frame, if `csvDict` was similar to the question's 1st snippet) - both unused.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the `apply`s like this:

```py
for key, df in csvDict.items():
    df['Cat_Frames'] = df['Cat_Frames'].apply(process).apply(cleandata).fillna(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in csvDict.items():
   df = pd.DataFrame(value)
   df
```

I think this is how you should traverse the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no processing of data from one data set/frame involving another data set, *don't* collect data sets.
Just process the current one, and proceed to the next.

The conventional name for a variable receiving an "unpacked value" not going to be used is `_`:

```
for _, df in csvDict.items():
    df['Cat_Frames'] = df['Cat_Frames'].apply(process).apply(…
```

- but why ask for keys to ignore them? Iterate the values:

```
for df in csvDict.values():
    df['Cat_Frames'] = df['Cat_Frames'].apply(process).apply(…
```